# Java for Loop evaluation

Tags: java, loops

I want to know if the condition evaluation is executed in `for` and `while` loops in Java every time the loop cycle finishes.

Example:

```
int[] tenBig = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

for(int index = 0;index < tenBig.length;index++){
    System.out.println("Value at index: "+tenBig[index]);
}
```

Will the `index < tenBig.length` be execute every time the loop cycle finishes?

Assumption and experience tells me yes.

I know that in this example the `tenBig.length` is a constant, so there won't be a performance impact.

But lets assume that the condition operation takes long in a different case.
I know the logical thing to do then is to assign the `tenBig.length` to a variable.

Still I want to be sure that its evaluated every time.

Comment: I know it is the case in c++. But is it for Java?

Comment: In your example, the middle part of the for will be evaluated 11 times.  Once you fix the spelling of `length` so that it actually compiles, that is.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it will logically evaluate the whole of the middle operand on every iteration of the loop. In cases where the JIT knows better, of course, it can do clever things (even potentially removing the array bounds check within the loop, based on the loop conditions).

Note that for types that the JIT doesn't know about, it may not be able to optimize specifically like this - but may still inline things like fetching the `size()` of an `ArrayList<T>`.

Finally, I generally prefer the enhanced for loop for readability:

```
for (int value : tenBig) {
    ...
}
```

Of course, that's assuming you don't need the index for other reasons.

Comment: The enhanced for loop has a noteable improvement: the expression (`tenBig` in your case) is only evaluated once, according to the JLS.

Comment: The only thing I don't like about the "enhanced" loop is that it doesn't check for null values. In other words, if the tenBig object is null, a NullPointerException is thrown, which makes sense, but it would have been awesome if the object is checked for null beforehand.

Comment: @Koekiebox: What do you think it should do in that situation? Treat it as an empty collection? Personally I think an NPE is the right result here.

Comment: Yes, threat it as an empty collection. The reason being laziness.

Comment: @JonSkeet:The terminating condition is evaluated for each loop, but the right side of the condition is evaluated as well. What is the reasoning behind this? I was expecting that if we had `for(int i = 0; i < totalDuration(); i++)` then `totalDuration()` i.e. the code that controls the total number of loops would be called only once

Comment: @Jim: the terminating condition is just an arbitrary expression. I don't know why you would expect *some* of that condition to be executed every time, but *some* of it to only be executed once. (Would you expect a condition of `totalDuration() > i` to end up with radically different behavior, simply because it's the same condition written the other way round?)

Comment: @JonSkeet: I have verified that the `totalDuration()` or whatever statement we have in the right side of the conditional operand is executed at every loop. I thought it would have been executed/evaluated only once at the init of the loop

Comment: @JonSkeet: I guess your point is that it would not have been possible to rearange the order of the operands if that was the case

Comment: @Jim: Well, more than that - it's just that it's a much simpler model to say "evaluate this expression at the end of each iteration". It's also how every language I've ever worked with behaves...

Answer (score 6):

Yes. Specifically, the condition part is executed *before* each loop body. So it's entirely possible that you never enter the body of the loop at all.

So taking your example:

```
for(int index = 0;index < tenBig.length;index++) {
    /* ...body... */
}
```

This is the logical (not literal) equivalent:

```
int index = 0;
while (index < tenBig.length) { // happens on each loop
    /* ...body... */

    index++;
}
```

Comment: The terminating condition is evaluated for each loop, but the right side of the condition is evaluated as well. What is the reasoning behind this? I was expecting that if we had `for(int i = 0; i < totalDuration(); i++)` then `totalDuration()` i.e. the code that controls the total number of loops would be called only once

Comment: @Jim - The whole thing (`i < totalDuration()`) is an expression, and nothing in the spec says that part of the expression will be remembered or reused. Remember that the expression can be anything (or nothing). But good news: If you want to call `totalDuration()` just once, in any of the languages I know that have `for`, you can do: `for (int index = 0, max = totalDuration(); index < max; index++)`.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the expression must be evaluated for each iteration of the loop to determine whether to stay inside the loop or continue program execution.

Remember, you can do things like this:

```
for(int a = 0, z = 26; a < z; a++, z--){
    // Do some work
}
```

In that case, both sides of the expression will change and must be evaluated for each iteration.

And you're right, if you have calculations in the for loop condition that can be moved out to a separate variable, you should do that:

```
for(int i = 0; i < ((someCount / 2) * 21.6); i++){
}
```

Could easily be:

```
int maxVal = (someCount / 2) * 21.6;

for(int i=0; i < maxVal; i++){
{
```

Answer (score 2):

Short Answer: the condition is evaluated **every time** so:

WRONG:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Math.random() * 50; i++) {
    System.out.println("" + i);
}
```

CORRECT:

```
double random = Math.random();
for (int i = 0; i < random * 50; i++) {
    System.out.println("" + i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the conditional expression is a *loop invariant* and you are running in JIT mode, loop optimizations such as [Loop-invariant code motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler_optimization#Loop_optimizations) can be done.

But when run in the interpreted mode, I *guess* there is not much optimization to do.

Answer (score 1):

Here are several bytecode [compiling examples from the JVM spec](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Compiling.doc.html).

As far as I know, the condition will be evaluated every time.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

`index < tenBig.length` will be execute before every time the loop cycle starts.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] tenBig = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

        for (int index = 0; isEvaluated() && index < tenBig.length; index++) {
            System.out.println("Value at index: " + tenBig[index]);
        }
    }

    public static boolean isEvaluated() {
        System.out.println("evaluated");
        return true;
    }
```

It will print `"evaluated"` just before cycles starts. And one more time before loop finishes.

Answer (score 0):

Do you ask wether the compiler caches the tenBig.length value since he knows it won't change during the loop? Or you ask wether the compiler automatically knows that the whole expression index < tenBig.length does not need to be evaluated for the next 9 times?

Answer (score 0):

It's going to be executed everytime the loop is entered, including the last evaluation which will yield index < length = false . 
Aside from this, even though the length of tenBig is const, the loop will always access this property so it would be ideal to assign it to a variable (even though it's not a reasonable speed gain in your example).