# Properties of a java for loop

Tags: java

Consider a simple java for loop:

```
for (int x = 0; x < bigArray.size(); x++ ) {
     Someobject object = (Someobject) bigArray.get(x);
      process(object);
 }

private void   process(Someobject object) {
  Someobject newobject = moreProcessing(object);
  bigArray.add(newobject);
 }
```

My observation is that the for loop will terminate even though I am adding additional objects to the end of bigArray and bigArray is constantly getting bigger.   Is this because the JRE fixes the value of the testing condtion (in this case x < bigArray.size()) before the for loop begins and never updates this value?

Comment: of what type is `bigArray`?

Comment: Are you sure that this exits?

Comment: If it was an array, such optimization makes sense.. for a List (not so much).. interesting.. are you sure it is an array?

Comment: @LewsTherin: If it was an array, this wouldn't compile at all...

Comment: This definitely *won't* terminate with the code you've given. Please post a short but *complete* program which demonstrates the problem - or I'm happy to post a short but complete program which demonstrates it *not* failing (until it runs out of memory).

Comment: @JonSkeet Yeah, that's why I am asking is it an array? The name `bigArray` is misleading.. yet he is using .add()

Comment: You are mistaken.  Post some real code that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: @JonSkeet - It *will* terminate ... with an OutOfStorage exception.

Comment: When I try to reproduce this, with an ArrayList<Integer>, I get *Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space*, as expected.

Comment: @HotLicks: Hence "until it runs out of memory".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem I see with the OP is that for an empty `bigArray` of type `List` the loop will terminate since it has to call `process` inside the loop to add elements and increase the `size` hence the condition in the for loop becomes `true` but the `size` is `0` at that point.
If the list is not empty then the `x < bigArray.size()` will always compare to the latest length i.e. including the objects added in `process`.
I assume that `bigArray` is of type `java.util.List`

Answer (score 0):

In most cases test condition will be evaluated before start of each iteration.

[More here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881660/java-for-loop-evaluation)

Comment: but, I hope, not in cases like mentioned in the question.